# different dimension numpy array broadcasting issue with '+=' operator

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm new to numpy, and I have an interesting observation on the broadcasting. When I'm adding a 3x5 array directly to a 3x1 array, and update the original 3x1 array with the result, there is no broadcasting issue.

```
import numpy as np
total = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(3))[:,np.newaxis]
print(f'init = \n {total}')

for i in range(3):
    total = total + np.ones(shape=(3,5))
    print(f'total_{i} = \n {total}')
```

However, if i'm using '+=' operator to increment the 3x1 array with the value of 3x5 array, there is a broadcasting issue. May I know which rule of numpy broadcasting did I violate in the latter case?

```
total = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(3))[:,np.newaxis]
print(f'init = \n {total}')

for i in range(3):
    total += np.ones(shape=(3,5))
    print(f'total_{i} = \n {total}')
```

Thank you!
hawkoli1987

Comment: In short, Python is wack. Although not an answer, relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGveIvwwSq4

Comment: in the first you create a new array each iteration.  It starts (3,1), but becomes (3,5). You aren't 'updating' the original (3,1).

Answer (score 1):

according to `add function` overridden in numpy array,

```
def add(x1, x2, *args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown; NOTE: unreliably restored from __doc__ 
    """
    add(x1, x2, /, out=None, *, where=True, casting='same_kind', order='K', dtype=None, subok=True[, signature, extobj])
    
    Add arguments element-wise.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    x1, x2 : array_like
        The arrays to be added.
        If ``x1.shape != x2.shape``, they must be broadcastable to a common
        shape (which becomes the shape of the output).
    out : ndarray, None, or tuple of ndarray and None, optional
        A location into which the result is stored. If provided, it must have
        a shape that the inputs broadcast to. If not provided or None,
        a freshly-allocated array is returned. A tuple (possible only as a
        keyword argument) must have length equal to the number of outputs.
```

`add function` returns a freshly-allocated array when dimensions of arrays are different.

In python, `a=a+b` and `a+=b` aren't absolutly same. `+` calls `__add__` function and `+=` calls `__iadd__`.

```
a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])
first_id = id(a)
a = a + b
second_id = id(a)
assert first_id == second_id  # False

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = np.array([3, 4])
first_id = id(a)
a += b
second_id = id(a)
assert first_id == second_id  # True
```

`+=` function does not create new objects and updates the value to the same address.

`numpy add function` updates an existing instance when adding an array of the same dimensions, but returns a new object when adding arrays of different dimensions. So when use `+=` functions, the two functions must have the same dimension because the results of the add function must be updated on the same object.

For example,

```
a = np.array()
total = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size=(3))[:,np.newaxis]
print(id(total))

for i in range(3):
    total += np.ones(shape=(3,1))
    print(id(total))
```

`id(total)` are all same because `add` function just updates the instance in same address because dimmension of two arrays are same.

Comment: Thank you so much Lazyer. It was super clear and helpful!

Comment: `+=` behaves different for immutable classes like python ints and floats.  Here we are dealing with a mutable array. whose values can be changed, but not attributes like dtype and shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [29]: arr = np.zeros((1,3))
```

The actual error message is:

```
In [30]: arr += np.ones((2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [30] in <cell line: 1>
    arr += np.ones((2,3))
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,3) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,3)
```

I read that as say that `arr` on the left is "non-broadcastable", where as `arr+np.ones((2,3))` is the result of broadcasting.  The wording may be awkward; it's probably produced in some deep compiled function where it makes more sense.

We get a variant on this when we try to assign an array to a slice of an array:

```
In [31]: temp = arr + np.ones((2,3))
In [32]: temp.shape
Out[32]: (2, 3)
In [33]: arr[:] = temp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [33] in <cell line: 1>
    arr[:] = temp
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (1,3)
```

This is clearer, saying that the RHS (2,3) cannot be put into the LHS (1,3) slot.

Or trying to put the (2,3) into one "row" of `arr`:

```
In [35]: arr[0] = temp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [35] in <cell line: 1>
    arr[0] = temp
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (3,)
```

`arr[0] = arr` works because it tries to put a (1,3) into a (3,) shape - that's a workable broadcasting combination.

`arr[0] = arr.T` tries to put a (3,1) into a (3,), and fails.